# VBA text to columns not parsing all data

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have two .csv files - in eyes they're identical, but something about them must be different.  **When data from the first one hits my text-to-columns macro, it does so only for part of the columns (first 39), skipping a portion (from 40 to the end going-right). This does not happen to data from the second .csv.**

Here is a sample of the data from both (they're generated from two different databases):

```
QRT NAME;REPORTING YEAR /;SOLVENCY CALCULA;LEGAL NAME OF TH;HOME COUNTRY;REPORTING CURREN;PORTFOLIO TYPE;ASSET HELD IN UN;PORTFOLIO;LINE ID;ID CODE;ID CODE TYPE;ID CODE LONG TEX;ORIGINAL CURRENC;ISSUER;ISSUER MIDDLE TE;ISSUER SECTOR;ISSUER COUNTRY;ISSUER CODE;ISSUER GROUP;ISSUER GROUP MID;PARTICIPATION;CUSTODIAN;CUSTODIAN MIDDLE;COUNTRY OF CUSTO;CIC ASSET CATEGO;CIC SUB ASSET CA;ASSETS SUBCLASS;TYPE OF SECURITY;TYPE OF COLLATER;BALANCE SHEET IT;EQUITY TYPE;RATING AGENCY;EXTERNAL RATING;MATURITY DATE;DURATION;VALUATION METHOD;QUANTITY;TOTAL PAR AMOUNT;UNIT SII PRICE;PERCENTAGE OF PA;ACCRUED INTEREST;TOTAL SII AMOUNT;ACQUISITION PRIC;WRITE-OFFS/WRITE;TOTAL AMOUNT LOC;IFRS ACCOUNTING;CLEAN VALUE IN O;DIRTY VALUE IN O;EXPOSURE IN ORIG;EQUITY;PROPERTY;FX RISK (DOWNSID;FX RISK (UPSIDE;INTEREST RATE (D;INTEREST RATE (U;SPREAD RISK BOND;SPREAD RISK STRU;SPREAD RISK DERI;;USE OF DERIVATIV;LONG OR SHORT PO;UNWIND TRIGGER O;TRADE DATE;PREMIUM PAID TO;PREMIUM RECEIVED;SWAP OUTFLOW AMO;SWAP DELIVERED C;SWAP INFLOW AMOU;SWAP RECEIVED CU;TRIGGER VALUE;DELTA;NUMBER OF CONTRA;CONTRACT DIMENSI;NOTIONAL AMOUNT;MAXIMUM LOSS UND;ASSET PLEDGED AS;FUND NUMBER;MATCHING PORTFOL;CURRENT INTEREST;INTEREST RATE FR;REDEMPTION;REFERENCE RATE L;FIXING FACTOR;FIXING SPREAD;QUOTATION TYPE;INTEREST RATE TY;REDEMPTION TYPE;QUOTED;LISTING COUNTRY;ANNUITY/INSTALLM;DISCOUNTING SPRE;FUNDS: FIXED INC;FUNDS: EQUITY QU;FUNDS: PROPERTY;FUNDS: CASH QUOT;FUNDS: ALTERNATI;FUNDS: FX-QUOTA;FUNDS: SPREAD DU;FUNDS: DURATION;BALANCE SHEET IT;
S.06.02.01;006.2016;M1;C;PL;PLN;L;N;LF_COMP;1;PLOPNPL00013;ISIN;X SA;PLN;9978;X;G47;PL;2594002C0DGL8KBA5491;18284;X;N;9448;ING BANK SLASKI;PL;3;PL31;EQ-STOCKS;Equity;NA;EQUI-EQUI;TYPE1;;;;;QMP;4900,000000;;31,470000;;0,000000;154203,000000;160424,170000;;;154203,000000;154203,000000;154203,000000;;49098,510000;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;;;;;;U;;;;;;;;;;;;;;NC;;;;0,00;;0,00;;;Per unit;;;Quoted;PL;;;;;;;;;;;31;
S.06.02.01;006.2016;M1;C;PL;PLN;L;N;LF_COMP;3;PL_CLF_PLN_BRE§2510;CAU;TD_PL_CLF_BRE BANK_PLN;PLN;9357;MBANK;K64.1.9;PL;259400DZXF7UJKK2AY35;727;COMMERZBANK;;9357;MBANK;PL;7;XT73;CASH-TD;Deposit;FIN-SEN;CASH-CASH;TYPE2;MDY;BBB;30.12.2016;0,500000;AVM;;448000,000000;;1,000000;4963,960000;452963,960000;;;;448000,000000;448000,000000;452963,960000;;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;-2655,240000;2436,920000;0,000000;;;;;;U;;;;;;;;;;;;;;NC;;;0,02210;0,00;;0,00;;;Percent;;;(none);;;;;;;;;;;;41;


QRT NAME;REPORTING YEAR /;SOLVENCY CALCULA;LEGAL NAME OF TH;HOME COUNTRY;REPORTING CURREN;PORTFOLIO TYPE;ASSET HELD IN UN;PORTFOLIO;LINE ID;ID CODE;ID CODE TYPE;ID CODE LONG TEX;ORIGINAL CURRENC;ISSUER;ISSUER MIDDLE TE;ISSUER SECTOR;ISSUER COUNTRY;ISSUER CODE;ISSUER GROUP;ISSUER GROUP MID;PARTICIPATION;CUSTODIAN;CUSTODIAN MIDDLE;COUNTRY OF CUSTO;CIC ASSET CATEGO;CIC SUB ASSET CA;ASSETS SUBCLASS;TYPE OF SECURITY;TYPE OF COLLATER;BALANCE SHEET IT;EQUITY TYPE;RATING AGENCY;EXTERNAL RATING;MATURITY DATE;DURATION;VALUATION METHOD;QUANTITY;TOTAL PAR AMOUNT;UNIT SII PRICE;PERCENTAGE OF PA;ACCRUED INTEREST;TOTAL SII AMOUNT;ACQUISITION PRIC;WRITE-OFFS/WRITE;TOTAL AMOUNT LOC;IFRS ACCOUNTING;CLEAN VALUE IN O;DIRTY VALUE IN O;EXPOSURE IN ORIG;EQUITY;PROPERTY;FX RISK (DOWNSID;FX RISK (UPSIDE;INTEREST RATE (D;INTEREST RATE (U;SPREAD RISK BOND;SPREAD RISK STRU;SPREAD RISK DERI;;USE OF DERIVATIV;LONG OR SHORT PO;UNWIND TRIGGER O;TRADE DATE;PREMIUM PAID TO;PREMIUM RECEIVED;SWAP OUTFLOW AMO;SWAP DELIVERED C;SWAP INFLOW AMOU;SWAP RECEIVED CU;TRIGGER VALUE;DELTA;NUMBER OF CONTRA;CONTRACT DIMENSI;NOTIONAL AMOUNT;MAXIMUM LOSS UND;ASSET PLEDGED AS;FUND NUMBER;MATCHING PORTFOL;CURRENT INTEREST;INTEREST RATE FR;REDEMPTION;REFERENCE RATE L;FIXING FACTOR;FIXING SPREAD;QUOTATION TYPE;INTEREST RATE TY;REDEMPTION TYPE;QUOTED;LISTING COUNTRY;ANNUITY/INSTALLM;DISCOUNTING SPRE;FUNDS: FIXED INC;FUNDS: EQUITY QU;FUNDS: PROPERTY;FUNDS: CASH QUOT;FUNDS: ALTERNATI;FUNDS: FX-QUOTA;FUNDS: SPREAD DU;FUNDS: DURATION;BALANCE SHEET IT;
S.06.02.01;006.2016;M1;C;PL;PLN;L;N;LF_COMP;1;PLOPNPL00013;ISIN;X SA;PLN;9978;X;G47;PL;2594002C0DGL8KBA5491;18284;X;N;9448;ING BANK SLASKI;PL;3;PL31;EQ-STOCKS;Equity;NA;EQUI-EQUI;TYPE1;;;;;QMP;4900,000000;;31,470000;;0,000000;154203,000000;160424,170000;;;154203,000000;154203,000000;154203,000000;;49098,510000;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;;;;;;U;;;;;;;;;;;;;;NC;;;;0,00;;0,00;;;Per unit;;;Quoted;PL;;;;;;;;;;;31;
S.06.02.01;006.2016;M1;C;PL;PLN;L;N;LF_COMP;3;PL_CLF_PLN_BRE§2510;CAU;TD_PL_CLF_BRE BANK_PLN;PLN;9357;MBANK;K64.1.9;PL;259400DZXF7UJKK2AY35;727;COMMERZBANK;;9357;MBANK;PL;7;XT73;CASH-TD;Deposit;FIN-SEN;CASH-CASH;TYPE2;MDY;BBB;30.12.2016;0,500000;AVM;;448000,000000;;1,000000;4963,960000;452963,960000;;;;448000,000000;448000,000000;452963,960000;;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;0,000000;-2655,240000;2436,920000;0,000000;;;;;;U;;;;;;;;;;;;;;NC;;;0,02210;0,00;;0,00;;;Percent;;;(none);;;;;;;;;;;;41;
```

Here is the text-to-columns formula I use:

note: data is copied from InputBook then the text-to-columns happens in ParamBook

```
Public Sub Load_input()

InputPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Comma Separated Values (*.csv),*.csv")

Call Fetch_Data

End Sub


Sub Fetch_Data()
    Dim InputBook As Workbook
    Dim ParamBook As Workbook
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    Set InputBook = Workbooks.Open(InputPath)
    Set ParamBook = ThisWorkbook


    '==========CLEAR CONTENTS OF DATA SHEET==========
    If ParamBook.Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
        ParamBook.Sheets("Data").Cells.Clear
    End If

'==========COPY INPUT AND PASTE INTO DATA SHEET==========
n = InputBook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
InputBook.Activate
InputBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(n, 1)).Select
Selection.Copy
ParamBook.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")


'==========TEXT TO COLUMSN IN DATA SHEET==========
K = ParamBook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate
For K = 1 To K
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(K, 1).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False
Next K


InputBook.Close
End Sub
```

**If there is something I can do with the code I'd appreciate some tips**, I'd rather not mess with how the .csv files are generated.

edit:

This text-to-columns code just works faster, but still the same issue.

```
'==========TEXT TO COLUMSN IN SAP_BW_DATA SHEET==========
K = ParamBook.Sheets("SAP BW Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAP BW Data").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAP BW Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(K, 1)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False
```

edit 2:

OK, I have narrowed it down - turns out, the problem does not lie with TtC functionality, but the way the data is pasted from the .csv file. The way it is currently set up only grabs a portion of the data (the same part which is being text-to-column'd), the remainder is not being pasted. Solving that will help the issue. Thanks everyone who participated in helping!

edit 3:

@cxw has fixed the issue, please see his post!

Comment: What I mean is that once it hits column 40, none of the data (besides the first row - weird) is there.  As in, from column 40 to the end going-right, it's all empty.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, the data is simply not there (check the whole right-area) - it just gets lost during the text-to-columns process. Additionally, I can't have consecutive delimiters treated as one due to some cells being left blank on purpose in the data.

Comment: Agreed. What is also strange is that when I try to use the excel text-to-columns function from the Data tab, it works without a problem on the data from the first .csv file (so no problem then).

Comment: @DaveR I just diffed the two sets of input you provided and they appear to be identical, at least after a copy/paste.  Is it perhaps a character-set issue?  Is one generated in a different locale than the other?

Comment: @cxw yes, the two .csv files have a different generation locations (two databases with essentially the same data). The first one is generated with SAS, the second takes that data, adds additional rows, and saves it as csv (this part is done via a VBA macro).

Comment: I have added an edit below the original code with revised code that does TtC on the entire first colums when the data is pasted from the csv - the effect is the same.

Comment: @DaveR OK, so **(1)** Remove or comment out `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` - that's there for production code, but it actually discards information you may find useful for debugging.  **(2)** Single-step through your code in the VBA editor, and at each step, check and make sure the right data is selected, and that the cells contain what you expect.  Perhaps the `Workbooks.Open` is splitting your input data into two columns, so the full data is never making it to `ParamBook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK — let's try this again.  When the obvious answers fail, check your inputs.

```
Set InputBook = Workbooks.Open(InputPath)
```

opens `InputPath` in the default mode.  You called these "csv" files, but really they are *semicolon* delimited, per your macro.  I suspect the two files have different extensions, and the problematic one is a `*.csv`.  Yes?

I just tried this on my Excel 2013 installation.  When I run the above line on a `*.csv` file containing your first test case above, Excel breaks it into columns at the commas.  Therefore, the data in the `InputBook` spans columns `A:S`, so your code only pulling out of column `A` wouldn't get all the data.  To fix this, I used

```
Set InputBook = Workbooks.Open(InputPath, format:=5)
```

Format 5 is "no delimiter" per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx).  When I do that, I get each row entirely in column `A`, and a manual text-to-columns works.

*Edit* Yes, extension does matter: When I rename my test file from `.csv` to `.txt`, a regular `Workbooks.Open` with no format specified doesn't split the columns.

Comment: This did it. Hats off to you sir :). The file is in fact semicolon delimited, and this tiny change sets everything right.

Comment: @DaveR Glad to hear it!  By the way, while you're online, check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about the site and what people will be looking for in questions.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** See the [actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39249550/2877364).

The problem is probably this line:

```
For K = 1 To K
```

You are changing the loop bound as you loop, which is almost never what you want :) .  (**Correction** See [Comintern's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247181/vba-text-to-columns-not-parsing-all-data/39249550?noredirect=1#comment65835280_39248187).)  (If you wanted flexible bounds, a `Do` loop would be a better choice.)  Try

```
LastRow = ParamBook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate  ' <--- should this reference ParamBook?
Dim CurrentRow as Long
Application.DisplayAlerts = False  ' move out of the loop for speed
For CurrentRow = 1 To LastRow
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False
Next CurrentRow
```

Also, your current code references *three* workbooks: `InputBook`, `ParamBook`, and `ThisWorkbook` (where the macro lives).  **Edit** I see you have initialized `ParamBook` to be a copy of `ThisWorkbook`.  I recommend that you stick with `ParamBook` throughout, then, as it will make it easier to port the code to an addin should you need to later on.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Thats a great comment about changing the loop bound as the loop continues - I'll refrain from doing that in the future. Still unfortunately, for some inexplicable reason - the problem persists.

Comment: The loop bound never changes after a for loop starts - it gets evaluated once.  The *real* problem with `For K = 1 to K` is that it evaluates from left to right, so it sets `K` to its initial value for the loop (1) and *then* uses it to set the loop bound. It will always be `For K = 1 to 1` regardless of what `K` is going into the structure.

Comment: @Comintern thanks - I didn't know the subtleties (never having tried it myself... at least not on purpose ;) )